# Retrieving and setting pixels individually

Tags: php

I'm trying to re-create a script I made in JavaScript; it bends an image by changing each pixels positions. I'm currently trying to port this to PHP, except when retrieving pixels and setting them, it doesn't appear correctly (I currently dont change the pixel locations). Below is my attempt:

```
<?php

header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$url = "https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($url);
$original = imagecreatefrompng($url); //Google's logo
$image = imagecreate($width, $height); // our new image

//loop through all pixels..
for ($x = 0;$x<$width;$x++){
    for ($y = 0;$y<$height;$y++){
        $rgb = imagecolorat($original, $x,$y); //get colour data from $x $y coordinates
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
        imagesetpixel($image,$x,$y,imagecolorallocate($image,$r,$g,$b)); 
        //set pixel data on our new image at the same location with the same data
    }
}

//retain a PNG's transparency
imagecolortransparent($image, imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($original);
?>
```

Here you can see (for testing purposes) I am using Google's logo, and im attempting to re-draw it pixel by pixel.. Below is the result. For some reason it only generates a very small portion of the image.. Any ideas?[image: Result of code]

**Edit:**
Here's the solution. As there isn't support for transparency using `imagecreatetruecolor()` I instead fill the image first with a white rectangle (if there is a solution for transparency, please create an answer).

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$url = "https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($url);
$source = imagecreatefrompng($url);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $width-1, $height-1, imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255,255,255,0));
//fill with white rectangle to look transparent, but note that it isn't. Changing alpha channel merely shows
//a black background.

for ($x = 0;$x<$width;$x++){
    for ($y = 0;$y<$height;$y++){
        $rgb = imagecolorat($source, $x,$y);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
        $colors = imagecolorsforindex($image, $rgb);
        imagesetpixel($image,$x,$y,imagecolorallocatealpha($image,$colors["red"],$colors["green"],$colors["blue"],$colors["alpha"]));
        //getting alpha from pixels for a real 'copy'
    }
}

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($source);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe use [`imagemagic`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) or one the other libs. They are a PITA but at least they are written in C or C++ and will be a lot faster than trying to do image manipulation in PHP.

Comment: Thank-you.. I would however prefer to remain using pure PHP if possible, or maybe Python if it is more suitable? @max

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php - http://phpimagick.com/

Comment: It does not matter if you use PHP or Python, the main thing is you want a fast `C` lib doing the heavy pixel crunching. Also there is probably  a built in transform that does what you are looking for.

Comment: `imagecreate` creates an indexed color image (e.g. for gif), which means it only allows 256 colors. you want `imagecreatetruecolor` instead. once you hit 256-ish pixels set, you run out of color index space and just end up setting a boolean false for the pixel's color

Comment: I forgot about `imagecreate()`'s limits, thank-you @MarcB (this does, as expected, fix my pixel issue - thanks). Do you know of any resources available to include transparency when using `imagecreatetruecolor()`? Unfortunately from what I've found, theres a balance between color support, or transparency.. My only option may be to fill the background as white first?

Comment: @max I personally would prefer to re-create any tranformations and algorythms for this, regardless of effeciency. However for other speed-dependant, or public released projects, I wold feel inclined to use them for better support and effeciency (and security).

Comment: Use `imageallocateocoloralpha`, specify a fully transparent color, floodfill the truecolor image with that.